# Unity requires access to Huawei HMS SDK, package name must end with .HUAWEI

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, huawei-mobile-services

I'm receiving an error in Unity that is preventing me to progress wiith my development.

> 3.[Description]:We found that your game contains a third-party account system,in-app paid games can not contain third-party account system in
>   addition to Huawei account; [Suggestion]:Please delete other account
>   systems except Huawei account,game account system needs to be
>   connected to Huawei account,it requires access to Huawei HMS SDK,
>   package name must end with .HUAWEI,guidance
>   link:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/hms [Test Environment]:
>   Wi-Fi connection,SD card, nova2 with Android 7.0+ EMUI5.1,mate9 pro
>   with Android 8.0+ EMUI8.0,Mate20 with Android 10 + EMUI
>   10.0.0，Multilingual environment.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation if you are using IAP Service - you will have to add suffix `.huawei` to your app's package name -> i.e.. `com.example.mygame.huawei`

Check out documentation: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/panorama-galleryconnect

It says:

> **2 . Creating an App**
>
> Create an app by referring to Creating a Project and Creating an App in the Project. Set the following parameters as
>   described:
>
> ● Package type: APK (Android app)
>
> ● Device: Mobile phone
>
> ● Package name: Must be the same as the APK name. **For apps using the
>   HMS SDK for in-app payment, the package name must end with .HUAWEI** or
>   .huawei. Otherwise, your app will be rejected by the reviewer.

According to my experience - it's "must have" only for games.

And there is no way to change the packagename once you set it up (uploaded apk/aab) in AppGallery Connect.

The only way is to delete the project and create a new one.

Comment: So you're saying that according to your experience, the package name only has to end in ".huawei" if the app is a game?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Huawei SDK so you can't use other third-party account systems. Choose between the other account systems in your game or Huawei SDK.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the official guideline https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-devguide-game, using Huawei ID (through Huawei Account Kit) and in-app purchase through Huawei IAP is a must for releasing games to Huawei AppGallery.

Changing package name is another must for having proper monetization, promotion and koint operations.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30216

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for your apps being rejected by the reviewer:

1. The developer should integrated [HUAWEI Account Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050048870) into the app.
2. The package name must end with **.HUAWEI** or **.huawei**.

If you want your app released , including Chinese mainland, HUAWEI Account Kit is mandatory.
For more information, see [Development Guide for AppGalleryKit Game](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-devguide-game).

Comment: This is unbelievable. Surely there must be a workaround for package name ending in .huawei ?? We have three live apps that we want to add in-app purchases to, but apparently this is impossible?

Comment: All right. There is a channel to fix this issue. 1. The App Signature cannot be the same as that of Google, try to use a new APK to sign it. 2. If an app has been released in AppGallery, you can apply for not changing the app package name.